# PHP Errors in CP when using DataGrab to parse remote feed

Tags: ee2, datagrab

I'm using the following:

```
EE v2.8.1
DataGrab 1.8.0
```

I have a number of data imports set up, using various formats such as CSV, XML, JSON, etc.  Since upgrading to EE 2.8.1, I get this Error message when I run the import on any of them, displayed at the top of the page in the control panel:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>   Message: Undefined index: entry_id
>   Filename: pages/tab.pages.php
>   Line Number: 195

The data import itself seems to work fine, but these ugly errors cannot be part of the final deliverable to my client.

The file referenced (system/expressionengine/modules/pages/tab.pages.php) is not part of the DataGrab add-on so I'm not sure what is going on.

I would appreciate any help.

Angel

Comment: If you have received your answer please check as answered.

Comment: Are you actually using the pages module? Are you setting URLs in the imported data? If you are not using the pages module then make sure the "add as page" checkbox is left unchecked.

Comment: Hi Jeremy - thanks for your reply - where would this checkbox be, in DataGrab or the Channel preferences?

Comment: The checkbox is in your datagrab settings.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that when you are importing your data you are creating channel entries. Pages is a tab in your channel entry that isn't getting referenced or set correctly because of this mass import of data. You might reach out to the developer of Pages to get this resolved.

Comment: Thanks - doesn't Pages come with EE?  I don't recall adding this module after the fact.

Comment: Yes pages does come with EE so you will need to reach out to Ellis Lab. If you are not using pages in your install at all go to Addons > Modules > and uninstall pages that should remedy your error.